# KingoRoot is stuck at 90%

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, kingo

I'm currently rooting a Samsung J1 Ace in Android 5.1.1 using KingoRoot in order to give [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) root access and move the apps, music, and other data files from its internal storage to a SD card. The internal hard drive has 8 GB and is almost full to the point where it can't update apps.

I've downloaded KingoRoot through the mobile browser as an **APK file** and enabled USB debugging. Unfortunately, 1 to 2 hours after starting the rooting process, the completion percentage is stuck at 90. When completion is at 90 percent, the rooting process is executed, however it seems frozen. The average duration of the rooting process is usually between 5 to 10 minutes.

I've searched through the Internet and found that switching it off via the power button maybe lead to an unstable root.

Is there any solution to this issue?

**EDIT**: The problem is gone after I have rebooted the phone and  but I get error code `0x15F6D5` which I have asked a [separate question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176922/what-is-kingoroot-error-code-0x15f6d5) on.

Comment: Why do you insist on using a tag for that word `apk`?

Comment: Because Kingo Root can be installed in two ways, either via Window or via Android. I want to emphasise that I chose the latter and therefore specified that I installed it using an APK file. I also have to note that the Windows version of Kingo Root is said to be more stable.

Comment: 'The problem is gone after I have rebooted the phone and but I get error code 0x15F6D5 which I have asked a separate question on' I posted an answer which I think may be helpful @PradanaAumars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I did was reboot the phone and the rooting process abruptly, yet safely, halted. Assuming that this issue is related to my [other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176922/what-is-kingoroot-error-code-0x15f6d5), it probably means that the device being rooted is **not supported**.