# What is KingoRoot error code 0x15F6D5?

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, system-error, kingo

I'm currently rooting a Samsung J1 Ace in Android 5.1.1 using KingoRoot in order to give [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) root access and move the apps, music, and other data files from its internal storage to a SD card. The internal hard drive has 8 GB and is almost full to the point where it can't update apps.

I've downloaded KingoRoot through the mobile browser as an **APK file** and enabled USB debugging. After a few minutes, it reports that the rooting process has failed and reports `ERROR CODE: 0x15F6D5`. I searched through forums and have found nothing on this error code.

What is it and how do I avoid it?

Comment: Try doing some "general" workarounds like cleaning up your internal storage or resetting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KingoRoot is stuck at 90%](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176915/kingoroot-is-stuck-at-90)

Comment: Do not double-post; instead, edit the original to include extra details.

Comment: The questions are different, one is a problem where the rooting process is *stuck at a certain percentage*, the other one is where the rooting process *has failed* with a (relatively) unknown error code. I'm not trying to double-post, I merely believe that these are two separate issues. Plus, I'm trying to shed light on this error code where I have found zero explanation on the Internet.

Comment: I've rebooted the phone and cleaned the internal storage a little, right now it has about 531MB of available space and it still returns an error.

Comment: The problem is, does the older issue (stuck at 90%) still occur? If the error code is the only thing you see now, it's definitely wiser to edit the old question to include the new phenomenon as an update; otherwise the separate questions would at least be somewhat justified.

Comment: Correct, I'll edit the other question right now. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Andy Yan Editing the OP with a different question is NEVER the appropriate action. SE is not a forum where users to talk each other through their issues. It is a living breathing encyclopedia for users to search through to find a specific answer to a specific question. The main point of asking is not to solve and move on. It is to post a copy of said question and answer for the thousands who will read it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this phone model on this Android version can be rooted using any one-click method, especially those using  apps! Those apps/softwares seem to since from android 5 (Lollipop).

You can still try the desktop version which I doubt will succeed.

Only [Chainfire's](https://www.chainfire.eu/) rooting method can work. Works on every Samsung devices I had to root. The method consists of flashing a modified recovery by entering the device in Download mode.

Also, I'll recommend you heading to XDA Developers  for extra details.

Follow the instructions form this [site](http://www.beritahuaja.com/2015/10/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-j1-ace-sm.html?m=1). Or this detailed rooting process from [XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/root-samsung-galaxy-j1-ace-sm-j111m-f-t3395520). Alternative solution from [Tsar3000](http://www.tsar3000.com/Joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2058:how-to-root-samsung-sm-j110h-galaxy-j1-ace-duos-android-v4-4-4-kitkat&catid=57:how-to&Itemid=104) site.

Find all rooting files for many Samsung devices from the developer's [site](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/).