# One-Click-Root Failed On Samsung J7 SM-J700H

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rooting, samsung-galaxy-j7

I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 running 6.0.1 marshmallow which i tried to root using One-Click-Root methods like desktop versions of "Kingroot" and "Kingoroot". However, "Kingroot" doesn't support my device type and "Kingoroot" gives "Root Failed" without showing any error code (as shown in the image below) . I have my phone's OEM Unlocked and USB Debugging on and I use ONE-CLICK-ROOT because it is believed to be the safest method (according to a quora discussion). So my question is, why is this happening ? And what could be a safe alternative to root my phone ?

[image]

Comment: Kingo root "is believed to be the safest method"? If I [check our site for "Kingo root"](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22kingo+root%22), it seems the safest method to get into trouble. Failing to gain root is even the best outcome. Alternatives include sudden adware appearance and certain apps being installed over and over, regardless of your removing them… Apart from that: No, I've got no Sammy, so I cannot help you obtain root on it. But you're welcome to check with our [rooting tag-wiki](/tags/rooting/info).

Comment: I have rooted several phones using kingo(isn't the best but it worked fine) .. Maybe Odin would work better ?

Comment: Granted: if it works out fine, people are not coming here to complain :) As I wrote, I don't use Sammys. So I have to pass this one over to someone else. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is KingoRoot error code 0x15F6D5?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176922/what-is-kingoroot-error-code-0x15f6d5)

Comment: @PradanaAumars How can that be a duplicate when it is about a particular error code, and this question specifically says there is no error code?

Answer (score 0):

One click root methods seem not to work on Samsung devices running Android Lollipop and above. They use an exploit that is already patched by either Samsung or Google.

So, the best method still the  [Chainfire's](https://www.chainfire.eu/) CF-Autoroot. I root mobile devices daily and this method seems to work on every Samsung devices. The method consists of flashing a modified recovery by entering the device in Download mode, no ADB here but OEM unlock should be required.

- Download this [file](https://download.chainfire.eu/824/CF-Root1/CF-Auto-Root-j7e3g-j7e3gxx-smj700h.zip?retrieve_file=1)
- Download [Odin flasher](https://androidmtk.com/download-odin-downloader-versions)
- Open Odin, click on AP/PDA and select the file you have downloaded.
- Boot the phone in download mode (volume down + power button the volume up to confirm)
- Click on Start and wait.

The developer has rooting files for  almost all Samsung devices from his [site](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/).